Who is greater Shiva or Visnu? or are they all equal?
Many people start fighting stating that Shiva is Greater or Visnu is greater and say negative things about. Also some consider Brahma Visnu and Maheshwar are the same. What's the case? Why are we Sanatani's divided by God?

requesting moderators to enforce their recommendation https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1033/please-stay-away-from-shiva-vs-vishnu-debate

People asking this question should first define the SCORING Metric to qualify as the strongest/greatest. One should clearly state all the categories and the passing grade to quality as the greatest. Else this is a useless question that people have been asking for ages because they don't have the time and courtesy to explore their own heritage and literary wealth left to them by their predecessors.

Such questions stems from the lack of Sadhana and balance in mental temperament. Just like asking which political party is the greatest in America. The reason one asks such a question is the lack of awareness towards the political history. Same goes here, which is a person lacks awareness towards their cultural history of the land that gave birth to diverse systems of spirituality. Then there are people who we call fanatics, such people have a lot of time in their lives to become self-proclaimed marketing managers for their SECT or Political Party. As if Sri Vishnu and Shiva need marketing.

A person belonging to abrahamic faith may be confused by looking at soo many temples and deities and scriptures and feel the need to ask such a question, but a person who has inhereted the wealth of this culture by being born in it is doing an injustice by not exploring it and choosing that which fits their sadhana.

You are being too harsh.  There is a sect active today whose Gurus STILL spread such superioroty/inferiority stories and lay people absorb those stories as if they are real @SanatanaDhara

@SK I agree that Gurus are still spreading it, but this is not new. They have been doing it from time immemorial, that is why I gave the "fanatic" and "marketing-manager" reference. Yes, I also agree it's a little sharp. But witnessing today's generation who are fortunate with technology and readily available information with online dictionaries, compared to our generation. Even if the Guru's say, there is no need to create a Ring-Match between Vishnu and Shiva. They can choose what appeals to them. But they rather come to social media and start a fruitless discussion, and I have seen soo many

particularly galling is the famous sectarian from the South who is universally regarded as a "Vedic expert" by preeminent TV anchors in Delhi and Bombay - he coolly spouts his sect's ideas as the whole of Hinduism and the anchors with little scripture-knowledge have no clue as to what he is doing @SanatanaDhara

religion is inherently divisive.  even if there is only one Gad, we'll divide ourselves as protestants or Catholics @AnjitKandel

Both Lord Shiva and Lord Vishnu are Supreme.

The Supreme Spirit has three conditions. In the form of Brahma, he is
the Creator, and in the form of Vishnu he is the Preserver, and in his
form as Rudra, he is the Destroyer of the Universe!

Mahabharata, Vana Parva, Section CCLXX
Brahma, Vishnu and Rudra/Shiva are simply three names and forms of Brahman.
Sri Hari (Avatar of Lord Vishnu) himself said that no one should see any difference between Him and Shiva.

Well-adored by the Rishis, by Brahma, and by all the deities, that
great God, the Lord of the universe, otherwise called by the name of
Hari, then addressed the illustrious Isana and said these words:-He
that knows thee, knows me. He that follows thee, follows me. There is
no difference between thee and me. Do thou never think otherwise.

Mahabharata, Santi Parva, Section CCCXLIII
Another example is given below:

Then Partha, with a cheerful soul, and joined hands and eyes expanded
(in wonder), gazed at the god having the bull for his mark [Shiva] and
who was the receptacle of every energy. And he beheld the offerings he
made every night to Vasudeva lying by the side of the Three-eyed
deity.

Mahabharata, Drona Parva, Section LXXXI
I am adding a passage that clearly states that only ignorant person sees any difference between Brahman, Brahma, Rudra and Hari.

Sri Bhagavan said: I, who am known as the supreme cause of the worlds,
its soul, its ruler, the witness of everything, the self-effulgent
being and attributeless Absolute - in truth I am both Brahma and
Rudra. O Learned one! Verily I assume different names like Brahma,
Vishnu and Maheswara, appropriate for the creation, preservation and
destruction of the universe, which I perform by assuming My Yoga-maya,
which has its three constituent Gunas of Sattva, Rajas and Tamas. In
Me, the all-comprehending and all-pervading Self, known as Brahman,
the ignorant man sees Brahma, Rudra and other entities as different.
Just as a man will not consider the members of his body like the head
and the limbs as different from himself but only parts of himself, so
does one who has taken refuge in Me sees all beings as parts of Me. He
attains eternal peace who does not perceive any difference between the
three - Brahma, Vishnu and Maheswara - who are one in nature and
pervade in all beings.

Srimad Bhagavata Purana translated by Swami Tapasyananda IV.7.50-54.
Brahma, Vishnu and Siva are same

Due to the disequilibrium of the qualities, Pradhana began to function
at the time of creation. From Pradhana, which is of the nature of Sat
and Asat, presided over by Isvara, the pair Brahma and Buddhi (cosmic
intelligence) are born simultaneously.
Then the Ksetrajna termed Brahma, of the nature of Tamas and the
unmanifest, manifests himself in the beginning, fully occupied with
sense-organs for all activities.
He, the unmanifest endowed with intellect shines forth with
brilliance. He is verily the first embodied being abiding in the
capacity of a cause.
He is equipped with indestructible knowledge and supreme lordship. He
is endowed with unobstructed dharma and detachment.
The knowledge, characterised by detachment, of that lord is unimpeded.
The intellect of Brahma identifying himself with that Lord, is
affected by Dharma and Aisvarya (supremacy).
Whatever he wishes mentally is created out of the unmanifest
naturally, due to its being controlled, due to absence of attributes
and due to his being the lord of the Devas.
In the capacity of Brahma, he becomes the four-faced creator; in the
capacity of Kala, he is the destroyer; in the capacity of Purusa
(Visnu) he is the thousand-headed lord. These are the three states of
the self-born God.
In the capacity of Brahma, the creator, he possesses Sattva and Rajas
predominantly; as destroyer (of the universe), Rajas and Tamas
predominantly; and as Purusa (Visnu), Sattva exclusively. Thus is the
state or course of attributes of the self-born Lord.
In the capacity of Brahma he creates; in the capacity of Kala he
withdraws (destroys) the worlds; in the capacity of Purusa he remains
unconcerned. These three are the states of the Lord of subjects.

Vayu Purana I.5.20-28

According to Bimba-pratibimba-vāda(बिम्ब-प्रतिबिम्ब-वादम्/Theory of Reflection), Suddha Māyā(Māyā associated with Sattva Guna) and Asuddha Māyā (Avidyā/अविद्य/Māyā associated with tamo guna) act like reflecting media. When Brahman is reflected in Suddha Māyā, it becomes Īśvara and is known as Saguna brahman(सगुण ब्रह्मन्/Qualified Brahman). Though Īsvara is also a Ĵivātman like us, but unlike us, He is the purest and the most virtuous soul attached with Prakriti with Sattva Guna. So Māya(माया/Prakriti/Illusion) becomes subservient to Īsvara rather than veiling Brahman.
How does Īsvara (ईश्वर) carry out His Duties? Creation, sustenance and destruction of the Universe with the help of Māya(माया/Prakriti/Illusion) are the Three Duties as described below:

Īsvara (ईश्वर) is God Brahma(ब्रह्म/பிரம்மா) while creating the Universe and the Māyā is called Goddess Saraswatī(सरस्वती) who is more of Rajo Guna(रजोगुण/Activity/Passion) required in order to carry out creation.
Īsvara (ईश्वर) is God Vishnu(महाविष्णु/மஹாவிஷ்ணு) who sustains the Universe and the Māyā is known as Goddess Lakshmī(लक्ष्मी) who is more of Sattva Guna(सत्वगुण/Pure/Goodness/Soft/Compassionate and Forgiveness) required in order to carry out sustenance.
Īsvara (ईश्वर) becomes God Rudra(रुद्र/ருத்திரன்) who destroys the Universe and the Māyā is none other than Goddess Pārvatī(पार्वती) who is more of Tamo Guna(तमोगुण/Ignorance/Destruction/Chaos) required in order to carry out destruction.

Conclusion:
The Trimūrties viz., God Brahma, God Vishnu and God Rudra are all forms of Īsvara who is Saguna brahman.

So your question “Who is greater Shiva or Vishnu? Or are they all equal?" is absurd and redundant.

